# maxNumberOfFiles not working properly in blueimp jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, file-upload, blueimp

I am using jQuery File Upload plugin (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) with CodeIgniter. I set maxNumberOfFiles option in my main.js to 5. Then, if I have 5 files already uploaded and try to upload one more, it gives me an error that file limit has been exceeded - this is fine.
However, if let's say, I have 4 files uploaded and then try to upload 3 more with multiple selection - the script allows me to upload all 3 of them. Obviously, I'd want an error message here instead. Is there any way to fix that without removing multiple file upload?

Answer (score 0):

Besides removing multiple file upload, there is no built in mechanism to do that in this plugin. I do not know of a plugin that supports this option. The blueimp plugin is my preferred file uploader as well.

You would have to modify the js files and evaluate how many files there are before the upload started, or after each file is processed. If you care to do that, I would start by looking at jquery.fileupload-process.js, but it will not be a trivial matter.